# Wordpress page not working after changing hosting

Tags: php, wordpress

I changed my hosting plan, now when I [create a new page](http://om-cafe.de/demo) it is not working, and also old pages ([such as this one](http://om-cafe.de/adresse/)) are not working either.

Only the [home page](http://om-cafe.de) is working.

Comment: Probably you have Apache's mod_rewrite turned off or not properly configured.

Comment: save permalinks again  from wp settings panel

Comment: This is running now on Microsoft IIS, so you won't have access to `mod_rewrite` anyway. Was the old host IIS too? cc @Michal

Comment: This website is not the software installation support forum of your hoster.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login then go to settings -> permalinks and just click "Save Changes"

as if you try opening via default non permalinks:

http://om-cafe.de/?p=1

its working.

Comment: login..? In wordpress login or cpanel login..

Comment: WordPress login

http://om-cafe.de/wp-admin

Comment: sorry but in my wordpress panel...no setting option..

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cb18m2d53 it should look like this. If you dont see settings panel, then your account is not admin account. You need admin privilages

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/04518m2h28

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29431/discussion-between-harshit-tailor-and-goran-jakovljevic)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29432/discussion-between-harshit-tailor-and-goran-jakovljevic)

Answer (score 1):

when you moving - from subdomain, host:

make sure that  .htaccess  file is ok

/index.php) RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

check database - wp-options-siteurl:
change 
http://my_old_domain.com
to:
http://my_new_domain.com

check also wp-config, if there are some settings pointing you to the old domain